# How applying Conv1D layer on the whole Matrix

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I have a Matrix each row reprsent a point with coordinate (x,y,z) I want to make feature extraction for each point using 3 shared MLP layers (64,128,1024) (Conv1D with kernal size 1) and at the end I want to aggregat the features using MaxPooling1D.
My question is How to define that my input is the whole Matrix (what I mean that I want each layer to applay on  the whole rows of matrix not just on one row )
I made code but I'm soure it's wrong

```
**Model=Sequential([
                    Conv1D(64,1,input_dim=(1,3),activation='relu')
                    BatchNormalization(axis=-1)
                    Conv1D(128,1,activation='relu')
                    BatchNormalization(axis=-1)
                    Conv1D(1021,1,activation='relu')
                    BatchNormalization(axis=-1)
                    MaxPooling1D(1)

  ])**
```

thanks in advance

Comment: So, your input shape is (m,n, 3). It's just an image.

Comment: no it's not an Image it's a Pointcloud

Comment: What's your input shape then? (len(point_cloud),len(point_cloud),,len(point_cloud)) ?

Comment: my input shape is(n*3) n points with 3 coordinate

Comment: But you're saying your input dimension is `(1, 3)`? So only a single 3D point per example in the batch. Your convolutional layers are not wrong as such, but they all have a kernel size of 1, which is just like having a `TimeDistributed` dense layer (or just a regular dense layer if you really only have a single 3D point per example).

Comment: the idea behind it that this conv layer is shared weights